# How do I adjust the abreviated footnote from author-title citation from the biblatex-chicago package?

Tags: biblatex, citing, biblatex-chicago

For a report I make for University, I have requirements for how to do my citations.
For the first occurence of a reference, they want the following footnote:

*John McLair, An introduction to Art (New York: Book Press, 2010), 83.*

For a next occurence, they want an abreviated footnote:

*McLair, introduction, 83.* (abreviated name, abreviated title, pages)

An example of latex code I tried but failed with:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[author-title]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{ref}
\begin{document}

test first citation \autocite{Kunstenaarsportretten}\\
test second citation \autocite{Kunstenaarsportretten}

\printbibliography[title={Bronnenlijst}]
\end{document}
```

The result I get in the footnotes of the pdf is:

*1. Lisa Smit and Nienke Bakker, Kunstenaarsportretten [in nl] (February 2020), 45–151.*

*2. Smit and Bakker.*

Though what I want is:

*2. Smit and Bakker, Kunst, 45-151.*

My reference bib file is (ref.bib):

```
@BOOK{Kunstenaarsportretten,
  title    = "Kunstenaarsportretten",
  shorttitle = "Kunst",
  author   = "Smit, Lisa and Bakker, Nienke",
  month    =  feb,
  year     =  2020,
  language = "nl",
  pages = {45-151}
}
```